# Wrong printing into .txt using sink()

Tags: r, sink

I am trying to output some anova results from R into a textfile using the sink() command, but I am getting some weird symbols.
**This is the code:**

```
sink(file)
print(title)
print("SUMMARY STATISTICS")
print("")
print("Summary grouped by factor ' roi'")
data %>%
  group_by(roi) %>%
  get_summary_stats(value, type = "mean_sd") #value cannot be a factor
print("")
print("Summary grouped by factor 'mA'")
data %>%
  group_by(mA) %>%
  get_summary_stats(value, type = "mean_sd") #value cannot be a factor
print("")
print("Summary grouped by both factors")
data%>%
  group_by(roi,mA) %>%
  get_summary_stats(value, show = c("mean", "sd", "se", "median"))

sink()
```

**... and this the result :(**

[image: example of the printed file by sink()]

**Software details:**
R studio is Version 1.4.1717
R Version 1.4.1717
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 0):

This is how `tibble` formats data for printing. It uses styled console output with the packages `cli` and `crayon`, which allow coloring and other styling with ANSI strings. Those ANSI strings are not compatible with `sink()`.

The easiest solution would be to convert the data into a more simple format like a `data.frame` for printing. Or you could also render the table into a text format using `knitr::kable()`.

```r
sink(file)
# ...
data %>%
  group_by(roi,mA) %>%
  get_summary_stats(value, show = c("mean", "sd", "se", "median")) %>%
  print.data.frame()  ## or knitr::kable()
sink()
```

The fact that `title` is printed as a function is because the symbol was undefined and therefore, the function body of `graphics::title()` gets displayed.

Comment: Oh, wow, it works perfectly with  'knitr::kable'! Thank you very much! ♥

Comment: Still, I wonder why in my windows version, I don't have this problem with the very same code...

Comment: Please accept this answer so the question gets marked as "solved". Or is there something I missed?

Comment: It is possible that `sink()` or some parts of the `cli` codebase behave differently on Linux and Windows. I personally don't think that it is a good idea to use `sink()` for any production code, but this is an intersting observation.